# Moved [from older laptop] HDD to new laptop

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, gpu

Older laptop die today. Prob MBO.

So pull out HDD [ that is ok ] and plugin in another laptop that all work fine.

Boot/start go fine and I got my GUI to work.
The issue is that he got freeze after few minutes in the load/idle.
Screen goes crazy colors since the older laptop has different GPU...

Newer done this thing before so just to ask is there any command that I can run to reconfigure/reload [ or something ] that apply new laptop hardware and things ?!
Or need a fresh install?
Is ubuntu budgie 18.04.1 LTS 64

Comment: What GPU old laptop? What GPU new laptop? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1108392/edit) question else answer impossible.

Comment: did you remove the display driver prior to removing the hdd? if not, does the new system have the same brand gpu? (ie. nvidia  or amd in both)? If no on both use a tty session to purge the driver and see if that helps.

Comment: Old laptop is: HP ProBook 6550b. intel i5; and "GPU" is that integrated thing: intel corp. core processor integrated graphics controller (rev 02). The "new" laptop is Acer Aspire 5250 (P5WE6) that use AMD GPU. I try to update ower additional drivers and it found nothing =\. and I didn't remove any options before I remove HDD and now I can't cos old one is dead =(. what command to purge that integrated thing if can be done ?

Comment: If all else fails, you could do a fresh install, yes. There are multiple ways of making a backup of your existing install first, depending on the resources you have available, like other hard drives, level of disk usage on the problem hard drive, BIOS vs UEFI setup, etc. But anyway, that shouldn't be necessary.